# Browser detects ISO-8859-1 encoding on UTF-8 cakePHP app

Tags: php, cakephp, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

On the server of my client, when I browse the application, the characters are wrong, because all of the Browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE) decode the page as ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8. Local works great, and on my server works fine too.

I have an application developed with cakePHP 1.3.12:

- The default encoding of all files is UTF-8 without BOM.
- All pages has `meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"`
- In core.php

  ```
  Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');
  ```
- In database.php

  ```
  var $default = array(
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'persistent' => false,
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'login' => 'aaa',
      'password' => 'aaa',
      'database' => 'aaa',
      'prefix' => 'app_',
      'encoding' => 'utf8'
  );
  ```
- The database, tables and fields collation is utf8_unicode_ci

I also put on the beginning of bootstrap.php:

```
echo mb_internal_encoding();
```

...and returns ISO-8859-1, so I put...

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

...but nothing change.

The server that work bad has PHP 5.2.16. I think it's a module or option on the client server, because local and in my server works fine.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: You should try to manually set the character encoding at the `<meta>`

Comment: I forgot to mention that each page has the meta. Now I edited the question adding that.

Comment: Is any HTTP header returned that specifies an encoding? Check for example with `curl -i http://...`.

Comment: I don't know how to check that. [HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET] => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 this is useful?

Comment: The only ways I can think to help track this bug is: 1) view source code and verify that it the <meta> markup is as expected and 2) see the headers the browser receives, using some browser extension or web dev tool.

Comment: The meta is fine. Here are the header:

Server Apache
P3P CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Vary Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding gzip
Content-Type text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length 534
Date Thu, 06 Oct 2011 23:10:19 GMT
X-Varnish 958149880
Age 0
Via 1.1 varnish
Connection keep-alive
X-Cache MISS

Comment: `Content-Type text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 ` Well, there you go. Figure out where that's coming from.

Comment: Yes, I know. I do not say clearly. So for that, is this question. I don't know who set that header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem by putting in the first line of app/config/bootstrap.php file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Simple and it even seems obvious, but in this hosting, the cakePHP application did not work as expected. The response header always answer Content-Type ISO-8859-1. Now with this change, it answered UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking if the .htaccess file on the server has something like this added :

```
AddType 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' html
```

Mime type could be different and some variatons in syntax exists, but it would look similar.

This would overwrite the files charset with the global charset set in .htaccess

Comment: No, the root .htaccess have AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Comment: There should'nt really be any other files on the serverside that could cause this, so your probably missing something somewhere, but I can't really understand exactly where that could be, looks like you've covered all the bases. Luckily there are smarter people then me on here, so hopefully one of those people will know where to look. If it's a shared webserver you could check with the host to make sure it's not something on their side.

Comment: If I missing something, In that case the app don't work local and on the other server. But it works. It must be something in my client server. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Your probably right, but could be anything? The client server could have Apache set up differently, be using a different PHP version, maybe suPHP, and a missing charset declaration could create the problem on the client server and not on your local server. It could also be the host has done something wrong in config files for you webserver, so contact them and ask if they can check their side, or restart the server for you.

Answer (score 0):

the database collation might differ from the collation for the `mysql` user in your `information_schema` (use phpmyadmin to check this).

in case you dont have the necessary privileges to change these settings, this might solve your problem, supposing that your page header `charset` is utf-8:

```
// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection = mysql_connect ($server, $username, $password);
$charset = mysql_client_encoding($connection);
$flagChange = mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connection);
echo "The character set is: $charset</br>mysql_set_charset result:$flagChange</br>";
```